# the Cauchy Condensation Test to establish the divergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have an exercise in my book about Cauchy Condensation Test. And I have one problem with understanding, how I can apply the theorem in one case and why I can't apply the same theorem in another case.

$\textbf{Theorem 1}$: Suppose that $X:=(x_n)$ and $Y:=(y_n)$ are stricly positive sequences and suppose that the following limit exists in $\mathbb R$:

$$lim\Bigg(\frac{x_n}{y_n}\Bigg):=r$$
$\textbf{a})$ If $r\neq0$ then $\sum x_n$ is convergent if and only if $\sum y_n$ is convergent.

So now my example. Use the Cauchy Condensation Test to establish the divergence of the series.

$\sum \frac{1}{n(ln(n))[ln(ln(n))]}$ = $\sum \frac{2^n}{(2^n)(ln(2^n))[ln(ln(2^n))]}$=$\sum \frac{1}{(n\cdot ln(2))[ln(n\cdot ln(2))]}$.

I can define $(x_n):=\frac{1}{(n\cdot ln(2))[ln(n\cdot ln(2))]}$ and $(y_n):=\frac{1}{n}$ like in my book. But I don't see how I can apply it.

How can I apply here my Theorem 1?  And why can't I make it in case $\sum \frac{1}{n(ln(n))[ln(ln(n))]^c}$. Maybe after answer of my first question, I can answer my second question by myself.

Thank you for help!

Comment: So I understood how I can apply this theorem. It's just a contrapositive. But why doesn't work this theorem with my second example?

Comment: Your theorem is not the Cauchy Condensation Test, it is the Limit Comparison Test. The Cauchy Condensation test says that given some positive sequence $x_n$, $\sum x_n$ converges if and only if the “condensed” series $\sum 2^n x_{2^n}$ converges.

Comment: You have to be careful here. The series that you have said are equal are not actually equal. The condensed series is not the same as the original series.